# Tex Studio: Why is my preamble orange?

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

In Texstudio's preamble section where I declare my packages, I have noticed that some of the texts are highlighted as orange.

There are no errors when compiling the document.

Can someone explain this curiosity?

[image]

Comment: Go to Options/Configure/Syntax Highlghting and you'll see why.  These appear to be commands that texstudio doesn't recognize as latex commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FAQ: Why does TeXstudio mark a command as unrecognized](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-texstudio-mark-a-command-as-unrecognized)

> TXS checks all LaTeX commands in the document for validity. This helps
>   you recognizing errors (typos and not loaded packages) already while
>   typing. If a command is marked as unrecognized, TXS did not find a
>   definition for it.

See the above link for more details.

Comment: But everything in the tex file loads file. no trouble.